# Is the function $g(x,h(z))=xf\left(\frac{h(z)}{x}\right)$ a convex function of $(x,z)$?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider $f(x)=2^x-1: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is a convex function. Then its perspective function is  $g(x,y) = xf\left(\frac{y}{x}\right): \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. According to S. Boyd's book "Convex optimization", we know that $g(x,y)$ is also a convex function.

Assume that $h(z): \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is convex. Is the function $g(x,h(z))=xf\left(\frac{h(z)}{x}\right)$ a convex function of $(x,z)$?

Appreciate any comments on this problem.

Comment: Note that $f(h(z))$ _is_ convex, because $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that over all of $(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the answer is no. If we take $h(z)=z^2$, then we get a function that looks like this:

[image: non-convex composition]

which is clearly not convex (in the image above, $y$ should be replaced with $z$).

Perhaps you need to restrict the signs of $x$?